# Get members from any type of a chat in Teams (personal, groupChat, or channel)?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a message extension app for MS TEAMS. This app will be preinstalled inside some organization. I should get members of any conversation type. There is a way via a graph
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id-for-teams}/members](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7Bgroup-id-for-teams%7D/members). I use application permission here.

But it looks like I can get users only for "group" (a team is inside Teams), which has channels.
I got 4 types of conversation type from ChannelAccount (namespace Microsoft.Bot.Schema):

- personal
- groupChat,
- channel,
- null

Also, there is bool isGroup property.

How can I get members of a specific chat, which can be any conversation type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this set of endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/conversationmember-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-1.0) to access both group chat and channel members. You don't technically need to get the "members" of a 1-1 chat, because it is only individual users (if you add a 3rd user, for instance, it will switch to becoming a group chat, I think). If you -do- want to get the -existence- of these 1-1 chats, you can use [this endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). Note that these are both BETA endpoints, so some caveats apply.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible do it without beta? Not sure that I can get approve for this.

Comment: not at the moment, you'd need to wait for these particular endpoints to move out of beta, or accept the risk that things -might- change in some way

Comment: I have checked your link above. I am going to use "/users/{id}/chats/{id}/members". Where can I get the second {id}? I think it should be chatId.

Comment: yes that's it, it's ChatId. You can get it in various ways, such as "/users/{id}/chats"

Comment: I have sent https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{aadObjectId}/chats, but get "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Specified method is not supported.". Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: oh, I see, Application permissions are Not supported.