# Where can I get groupId?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a message extension app for MS TEAMS. I am going to use [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id-for-teams}/members](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7Bgroup-id-for-teams%7D/members) for getting "members". Where can I get group-id-for-teams? ChannelAccount data looks like

```
"conversationAccount": {
  "isGroup": true,
  "conversationType": "channel",
  "id": "34:v7g123e0ee5a4502943cfcf24f12123c@thread.skype",
  "name": null,
  "aadObjectId": null,
  "role": null,
  "tenantId": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"
```

There is some Id but it is not group-id-for-teams.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to us We will investigate and if we require further information we will reach out. Best regards, Teams Platform

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? Are you looking for the members of a Team?

Comment: Yes, @Trinetra-MSFT I want to get members of a Team. See also my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62777518/get-members-from-any-type-of-a-chat-in-teams-personal-groupchat-or-channel

Comment: Try to run this piece of code
  var member = await TeamsInfo.GetMemberAsync(turnContext, turnContext.Activity.From.Id, cancellationToken);

Comment: Make sure your app is installed in that team you are trying to fetch the members for it

Comment: yeap, @Trinetra-MSFT I am using this code. My customer wants the message extension should be available without installation. That why I want to switch on graph.If the app has permission I can get members without installation, right?

Comment: Yes you can for that you need to make an explicit call to get the group ID :
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups) in your organisation, this will show or you can check the API which gives you the groups you are member of

Comment: Regarding "you are member of". Yes, it is an option. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. I can't send a request with "on behalf of a user". Because admins don't give permissions for every user in an organization for that request. They can give permissions for the application.

Comment: Did you tried with Group.ReadWrite as an Application permissions?

Comment: No, I didn't try. Why should I use Group.ReadWrite as Application permission? I use Chat.ReadBasic.All, Group.Read.All, GroupMember.Read.All, User.Read, User.Read.All as Application permissions

Answer (score 0):

You can query `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups` to get all groups. You can search for you group and get the id.

For teams you can query `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams` to get all teams which you are part. There is no api for all teams i guess.

You can right away go to Graph explorer(https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), sign in and run those query and see result.